# Graph for the curved portion of the equation $y^y=x^x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

For the equation $y^y=x^x$, I know that one solution is the line $y=x$ (for $x > 0$), and is shown in this graph here: [$y^y=x^x$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tfbb0psc6a). However, when I see that graph, I also see a curve that goes from $(0, 1)$ to $1, 0$. Is there an equation (i.e. analytical solution) for just that curve?

I played around with equations, and have discovered that equations in the form $y=\frac{1}{x+a}-a$ kind of fit, but not really.
For example, $y=\frac{1}{x+.62}-0.62$ is close, but not really.

I am a high school student and am taking Pre-Calculus, and so my knowledge of advanced functions are limited. However, I do welcome more complicated functions.

Comment: When $x$ is less than the value where the two curves intersect (which I think is $e^{-1}$), the solution is given by the product log function: $y = \frac{\ln(x^x)}{W(\ln(x^x))}$ which is equivalent to $e^{W(\ln(x^x))}$.

Comment: @VarunVejalla What is the name of the function W(x)?

Comment: It is the [Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) also known as the product log function. It is the inverse of $x e^x$.

Comment: @VarunVejalla Do you have a graph of the function $y=\frac{\ln(x^x)}{W(\ln(x^x))}$?

Comment: It is [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5BLog%5Bx%5Ex%5D%2FProductLog%5Bln%28x%5Ex%29%5D%2C+%7Bx%2C+0%2C+1%7D%5D), but $y \not = x$ only for $x$ less than some value (I think $e^{-1}$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want a "simple" and quite accurate function to represent the curved part of function
$$y=\frac{\log(x^x)}{W(\log(x^x))}\qquad \text{for} \qquad 0 \leq x \leq \frac 1e$$ hoping that you do not require too much accuracy for small values of $x$, you could use the series expansion

$$y=\frac 1 e \sum_{n=0}^p (-1)^n a_n\,(ex-1)^n $$ where the first coefficients make the sequence
$$\left\{1,1,\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{9},\frac{17}{270},\frac{31}{810},\frac{151}{5670},
   \frac{547}{28350},\frac{7541}{510300},\frac{763}{65610},\frac{14281213}{151559100
   0}\right\}$$

**Edit**

Some numerical results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
x & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 0.000 & 0.966579 & 1.000000 \\
 0.025 & 0.895605 & 0.902904 \\
 0.050 & 0.833657 & 0.835955 \\
 0.075 & 0.778631 & 0.779374 \\
 0.100 & 0.729009 & 0.729241 \\
 0.125 & 0.683692 & 0.683760 \\
 0.150 & 0.641883 & 0.641902 \\
 0.175 & 0.602997 & 0.603001 \\
 0.200 & 0.566596 & 0.566597 \\
 0.225 & 0.532350 & 0.532350 \\
 0.250 & 0.500000 & 0.500000 \\
 0.275 & 0.469345 & 0.469345 \\
 0.300 & 0.440221 & 0.440221 \\
 0.325 & 0.412494 & 0.412494 \\
 0.350 & 0.386053 & 0.386053
\end{array}
\right)$$

If you want a "super simple" approximation use
$$y=1-\frac{(e-1)}{\sqrt[3]{e}} x^{2/3}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. However, I'm not sure if it approximates the entire curve too well, it only approximates the area in the vicinity of $\frac{1}{e}$ well, using the sequence you have given. Therefore, I have upvoted, but will withhold the checkmark. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5m07abeesj

Comment: @KingLogic.Let me check again

Comment: @KingLogic. Checked ! Look at my edit for values.

Comment: @KingLogic. Try $y=1-\frac{(e-1)}{\sqrt[3]{e}} x^{2/3}$ !

Comment: Btw, is there a closed form for its factor $\frac{y^y-x^x}{y-x}?$

Comment: @Narasimham. If you have one, please, give it (at least to me). Cheers :-)

Comment: I don't have, thought maybe there is an advanced result with W !